# CSS is not picking up in iphone/ipad simulator

Tags: mobile, cordova

I am using xcode and phonegap for mobile development.When i run the application with simulator,it does not apply any stylesheet. Please let me know how to get rid of this issue.

Here is the index.html Page code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,minimum-scale=1 user-scalable=no,width = 320" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=0;" />
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="default" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jqtouch.css" />
    <link href="theme.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="Jquery.1.6.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="phonegap.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jqtouch.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
        var jQT = new $.jQTouch({});
  </script>
</head>
<body >
<div id="jqt">
    <div id="home">
        <div class="toolbar">
            <h1>
                NIAID</h1>
        </div>
        <ul class="edgetoedge">
            <li class="arrow"><a href="#get">Search Users</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="get">
        <div class="toolbar">
            <h1>
                NED - Search Users</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="info">
            <center>
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            First Name :
                            <input type="text" id="txtFirstName" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            Last Name :
                            <input type="text" id="txtLastName" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <input type="button" id="btnSearch" value="Search" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </center>
        </div>
        <ul class="edgetoedge" id="search-results">
            <li class="sep">Results</li>
        </ul>
        <ul id="placeholder" class="edgetoedge">
        </ul>
        <div class="toolbar">
            <a class="back" href="#" onclick="ClearContents()">Back</a></div>
    </div>
    <div id="Details" style="display: none">
        <div class="toolbar">
            <h1>
                User Details</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="info">
            <div id="result">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="toolbar">
            <a class="current" href="#" onclick="jQT.goBack();">Back to results</a></div>
    </div>


</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Please let me know what am doing wrong here.

Thanks,
Vishnu

Answer (score 0):

I can't be sure why no css is being applied but the check the following

1. are you sure you have the right path to css and js files? for js it seems that one js file is under scripts and the other in the same folder as index, the css also seems to be in the same folder - check if that may be your problem. I'm not even sure the the scripts leads to the right path - you can try ./scripts/file
2. you have 2 viewports meta tags, I'm quite sure this is a mistake. they also partly contradict each other. so probably the browser would override the first one with the second one
3. to make sure you don't use phonegap api before the device is loaded. best practice to load the page js (besides the libraries) after the devices fires the deviceready event. like this example:

   ```
       $(document).ready(function(){
           document.addEventListener('deviceready',function(){
               var script = document.createElement('script');
               script.type = "text/javascript";
               script.src = "./path/to/yourjsscript.js";//change to fit the path
               document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(script);
           },false);
       });
       </script>
   ```

Comment: Thanks for the response.CSS is picking up now.But if i include jqtouch.css and theme.css .it is showing black screen.